# Write a letter right below mdframed

Tags: mdframed

is there a way to write something just right below an mdframed-box?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=5mm, rightmargin=5mm]
    Text of the full space of the mdframed. Just tried to fit the space fully.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Next I will add the output with an added red letter:
[image]

I want to add a letter or a symbol (square, triangle, circle, whatever) directly in that corner. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Well, your title and text is misleading. You don't want to have the letter **below**, you want it **inside** at the lower right corner ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the letter at the end of the line,
just use `\hfill` to set the letter at the end of the line

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mdframed, color}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=5mm, rightmargin=5mm]
    Text of the full space of the mdframed. Just tried to fit the
    space fully. \hfill\textcolor{red}{S}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to move the letter further down and right, use `\rlap` and `\raisebox` judiciously, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mdframed, color}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=5mm, rightmargin=5mm]
    Text of the full space of the mdframed. Just tried to fit the
    space fully. 
    \hfill\rlap{\raisebox{-\fboxsep}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace{\fboxsep}\textcolor{red}{S}}}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your 2nd approch will do it. Thank you!